# Sticky headers following their backgrounds on scroll - pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I am a beginner in JS. And I've got a task to create a column consisting of several blocks. Each block should have its header. Each header should be of a different color. On scroll when the next header reaches the top, it should stick to the top and change the background color of the preceding header to the color of the header that recently came to the top. How can I do this using pure JS and taking into account responsiveness and adopting to landscape direction?
[sample gif](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxwJ9t4g_Zx1blRESTlodWNOeFk)
Thank you

UPD: So far, I've got the following code done. When I run it on my laptop it goes more or less fine. But as soon as I resize the window the sticky header escapes to the right. What is the secret that I missed there?

```js
! function(name, definition) {
  if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports) module.exports = definition();
  else if (typeof define == 'function') define(definition);
  else this[name] = definition();
}('sticky', function() {

  return function sticky(el, top, options) {

    var requiredOriginalStyles = ['position', 'top', 'left', 'z-index'];

    var requiredTop = top || 0;
    var originalRect = calcRect(el);
    var styles = {
      position: 'fixed',
      top: requiredTop + 'px',
      left: originalRect.left + 'px',
      // width: originalRect.width + 'px',
      'z-index': 9999
    }

    if (options && options.enforceWidth) {
      styles.width = originalRect.width + 'px';
    }

    var originalStyles = {}
    requiredOriginalStyles.forEach(function(key) {
      originalStyles[key] = el.style[key];
    });

    var onscroll;
    if (window.onscroll) {
      onscroll = window.onscroll;
    }

    window.onscroll = function(event) {
      if (getWindowScroll().top > originalRect.top - requiredTop) {
        for (key in styles) {
          el.style[key] = styles[key];
        }
      } else {
        for (key in originalStyles) {
          el.style[key] = originalStyles[key];
        }
      }
      onscroll && onscroll(event)
    }
  }

  function calcRect(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var windowScroll = getWindowScroll()
    return {
      left: rect.left + windowScroll.left,
      top: rect.top + windowScroll.top,
      width: rect.width,
      height: rect.height
    }
  }

  function getWindowScroll() {
    return {
      top: window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
      left: window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft
    }
  }

});

var headers = document.querySelectorAll('.header')
Array.prototype.forEach.call(headers, function(header) {
  sticky(header);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font: 14px/2 Roboto, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section:first-child {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.header--initial {
  background: yellow linear-gradient(to right, grey, transparent, grey);
}

.header--main-start {
  background: grey linear-gradient(to right, grey, yellow);
}

.header--main-end {
  background: yellow linear-gradient(to right, yellow, grey);
}

.header--final {
  background: grey linear-gradient(to right, yellow, transparent, yellow);
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #333;
}

.placeholder {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="header header--initial"></div>
  <div class="placeholder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum veritatis dolorem ducimus atque cumque accusantium accusamus aliquam excepturi nulla illo corrupti vitae repellendus quod, molestias esse est nisi, omnis odit.</p>
    <p>Soluta autem, aut voluptate quo debitis quidem exercitationem quisquam nostrum accusamus aliquam perspiciatis nobis dolores est dolorum provident! Asperiores explicabo fugit, unde eveniet ut nesciunt autem molestiae nam totam fuga.</p>
    <p>Vel nisi a dolorem itaque eaque mollitia ipsum repellat modi placeat, eveniet consectetur officia veniam ab esse, adipisci quia unde excepturi consequuntur expedita quas! Sed porro sunt soluta totam delectus!</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="header header--main-start"></div>
  <div class="placeholder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum qui quidem rem ducimus, labore, id praesentium error quasi nobis saepe illo consequuntur voluptatum dolores illum facere, itaque dicta eveniet, quod.</p>
    <p>Expedita dolore vel odit est nemo quis nihil ipsam quo vitae repellendus ex optio illo magnam quidem a ullam dolores reiciendis facilis deserunt eligendi cum, sit eaque? Et, nam odio!</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="header header--main-end"></div>
  <div class="placeholder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum distinctio nobis excepturi sunt voluptates, saepe nam error laudantium velit autem quaerat placeat quisquam est dolore cum quidem, in ad sit!</p>
    <p>Ex impedit deserunt, quibusdam ipsam blanditiis sunt tempore ab aut? Cum assumenda iure minus fugiat, rem nemo alias voluptatem, ad neque temporibus blanditiis aliquam earum praesentium vero labore ducimus, a.</p>
    <p>Velit, suscipit officiis. Praesentium, explicabo similique maiores repellendus. Cupiditate voluptate corporis nisi doloremque aspernatur, autem aut officia. Eaque deleniti alias, modi dolorem quod qui debitis illo. Aut, ipsam. Hic, autem.</p>
    <p>Maiores consequatur, aliquid possimus quae asperiores corporis repudiandae! Quod id iure at dolorem consectetur, sed, debitis libero perspiciatis, numquam ea, fugit repudiandae sunt consequatur. Harum optio ut doloribus distinctio adipisci!</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="header header--final"></div>
  <div class="placeholder">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt quisquam doloribus, commodi mollitia saepe nesciunt esse animi totam beatae facere tenetur veniam quas expedita iusto ipsa provident hic! Minima, repellendus.</p>
    <p>Accusamus voluptatibus laudantium commodi nostrum obcaecati impedit atque doloremque officiis? Iste necessitatibus, aperiam. Vitae facilis ipsam vel, sequi perspiciatis fugit, dolores expedita quaerat reiciendis beatae iste hic molestias cumque! Necessitatibus!
      </p>
    <p>Cum, dolore. Dolore corporis voluptas consequatur ratione fuga, laboriosam quisquam qui corrupti ut, in nam pariatur iste blanditiis nulla autem praesentium, optio maxime. Consequuntur vitae nemo eius similique, fugiat saepe.</p>
    <p>Recusandae iure iusto ut vero dolorum, hic quos libero nostrum esse enim laudantium velit modi culpa, consequatur vel officiis exercitationem quod repellat, voluptas impedit nesciunt beatae similique itaque distinctio? Sapiente.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is just normal sticky header thing. There are a lot of resources online about implementing it.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @glennsl Any comments given the changes?

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone will read through this much code. You might want to be more specific and have a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try making your `<body>` element have an `onresize` attribute that updates the styles of the dropdown:

```
<body onresize="updHead()">
```

Comment: Thank you, Samuel - I tried to do so, but it didn't help (